# Simple C program using <string.h> methods not running

Tags: c, string.h

I have the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char first[] = "foo";
    char last[] = "bar";
    
    strcat(first, last);
    
    printf("%s\n", first);

    return 0;
}
```

it compiles but when I run it I get the following error:

`zsh: illegal hardware instruction  ./output/strfunc.out`

For reference I'm using clang to compile the code:

```
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

I can't seem to be able to use any of the methods associated with <string.h>. I have looked online but found nothing, any ideas?

Comment: `first` is sized to fit exactly `"foo"`. Adding to it with `strcat` results in undefined behaviour. Try explicitly sizing the array `char first[128] = "foo";`

Comment: `first` is an array of size 4.  It does not have any space to append more data to it.

Comment: Change `char first[] = "foo";` to `char first[7] = "foo";` so that `foo` has enough space for storing the resulting string `"foobar"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char first[] = "foo";
```

That tells the compiler to create an array that is sized exactly to fit the initializer string. It has no space for any more characters to be added. So trying to add a string to the end with `strcat` results in a buffer overflow and hence Undefined Behaviour.

One solution is to explicitly size the array:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 32
char foo[MAX_SIZE] = "foo";
```

Comment: So in the use case above I would need to explicitly size the array foo to the length of the string + 1? (bytes-wise)

Comment: Yes you need to size the array to be able to fit the final string. Which would be at least `strlen("foobar")+1`